# Can't add new hostname to google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to add my new hostname "www.malaysiakini.com" to google app engine web address, but it fail to do so.

I was mapped my hostname to google pagespeed since last year. And i already remove google pagespeed service from the project list today.

I thought the hostname is now not being use by any service. Then, i tried to add the hostname into google app engine web address, i get the error message showing "Already used, please remove previous mapping first".

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Someone might be able to help you if you explained in more details what you are trying to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: i contacted google support. It is their internal system issue, they are fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can use that name again, even if you deleted that app or the *name.appspot.com* domain seems not to exist. I think Google keeps a list of used app-names and I dont know if it's possible to delete an unused name from that list after you registered it, even if you deleted the app itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to: https://appengine.google.com/settings?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
You should be able to see a button: "Add Domain" click on it and it will take you into the process of assign your own domain for this specific project.

Comment: i have no problem to add domain into google-app-engine. i meant i can't add new hostname into it.

Comment: Ohh... I see - I guess you might need to start a new app and assign the new domain for it.